Yup Conditional Validation for an Array of Objects
I am implementing Yup validations for a dynamic form using React-Hook-Form. The validation requirements depend on the value of contentType. If contentType is either undefined or "Blog Post", the blogPostSchema should be required, if contentType is "Product Listing", then productListingSchema must be required, and if contentType is "Event", the eventSchema should be required.
How can I structure my Yup schema to handle these conditions correctly?
Regardless of the value present in contentType, the blogPostSchema, productListingSchema, and eventSchema are still being marked as required.
Here's my current code:
import * as yup from "yup";

const blogPostSchema = yup.object().shape({
  blogPostBody: yup.string().required("Body is required"),
  blogPostTags: yup.string().required("Tags are required"),
});

const productListingSchema = yup.object().shape({
  productName: yup.string().required("Product Name is required"),
  price: yup
    .number()
    .required("Price is required")
    .typeError("Price must be a number")
    .positive("Price must be a positive number")
    .min(1, "Price must be at least 1"),
  category: yup.string().required("Category is required"),
});

const eventSchema = yup.object().shape({
  eventDate: yup
    .date()
    .required("Event Date is required")
    .typeError("Please enter a valid date"),
  location: yup.string().required("Location is required"),
  description: yup.string().required("Description is required"),
});

export const schema = yup
  .object({
    contentType: yup.string().required("Content type is required"),
    title: yup.string().required("Title is required"),
    author: yup.string().required("Author is required"),
    blogPosts: yup
      .array()
      .of(blogPostSchema)
      .when("contentType", {
        is: (value) => value === "Blog Post" || value === undefined,
        then: (schema) => schema.required(),
        otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
      }),
    productListings: yup
      .array()
      .of(productListingSchema)
      .when("contentType", {
        is: "Product Listing",
        then: (schema) => schema.required(),
        otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
      }),
    events: yup
      .array()
      .of(eventSchema)
      .when("contentType", {
        is: "Event",
        then: (schema) => schema.required(),
        otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
      }),
  })
  .required();


The first mistake I saw in your code is not using functions for then and otherwise, if you are using the latest version of yup.
Here is the answer from SO that might help with that.
Now, I did not understand if title and author have to be required all the time, for every contentType. From your proposed schema, I suppose they should be required all the time.
import * as yup from "yup";

// Define schemas for different content types
const blogPostSchema = yup.object().shape({
  blogPostBody: yup.string().required("Body is required"),
  blogPostTags: yup.string().required("Tags are required"),
});

const productListingSchema = yup.object().shape({
  productName: yup.string().required("Product Name is required"),
  price: yup
    .number()
    .required("Price is required")
    .typeError("Price must be a number")
    .positive("Price must be a positive number")
    .min(1, "Price must be at least 1"),
  category: yup.string().required("Category is required"),
});

const eventSchema = yup.object().shape({
  eventDate: yup
    .date()
    .required("Event Date is required")
    .typeError("Please enter a valid date"),
  location: yup.string().required("Location is required"),
  description: yup.string().required("Description is required"),
});

export const schema = yup.object().shape({
  contentType: yup.string().required("Content type is required"),

  title: yup.string().required("Title is required"),
  author: yup.string().required("Author is required"),

  blogPosts: yup.array().when("contentType", {
    is: "Blog Post",
    then: () =>
      yup.array().of(blogPostSchema).required("Blog Posts are required"),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
  }),

  productListings: yup.array().when("contentType", {
    is: "Product Listing",
    then: () =>
      yup
        .array()
        .of(productListingSchema)
        .required("Product Listings are required"),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
  }),

  events: yup.array().when("contentType", {
    is: "Event",
    then: () => yup.array().of(eventSchema).required("Events are required"),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired(),
  }),
});


Notice how otherwise and then are functions. Title and Author are now always required fields, regardless of the contentType. The content-specific fields are still conditionally required based on the selected contentType.
Let me know if this helps!
Here is the sandbox that shows the demo

Hi, sorry for the late response.
I was able to resolve the issue with the code suggested by Claude I've added in the below answer comment.

The following code worked for me:
export const schema = yup.lazy((values) => {
  const baseSchema = {
    contentType: yup.string().required("Content type is required"),
    title: yup.string().required("Title is required"),
    author: yup.string().required("Author is required"),
  };

  switch (values.contentType) {
    case "Blog Post":
    case undefined:
      return yup.object({
        ...baseSchema,
        blogPosts: yup
          .array()
          .of(blogPostSchema)
          .min(1, "At least one blog post is required"),
      });
    case "Product Listing":
      return yup.object({
        ...baseSchema,
        productListings: yup
          .array()
          .of(productListingSchema)
          .min(1, "At least one product listing is required"),
      });
    case "Event":
      return yup.object({
        ...baseSchema,
        events: yup
          .array()
          .of(eventSchema)
          .min(1, "At least one event is required"),
      });
    default:
      return yup.object(baseSchema);
  }
});

